# why compiler is used for sass files while they can be run through terminal

Tags: sass

Can anyone please help explain this? I am new at using Sass. But I cant understand why people use compiler for sass files when they can be run through terminal.

Comment: By [tag:sass], do you mean the language that is compiled to CSS for browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same question some time ago when I was learning SASS.

I kept wondering why most tutorials involved using GRUNT / GULP or some kind of task runner when there where sass proprietary commands even for live-watching your files with a command such as:

```
sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets
```

I will quote myself here in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276283/is-console-sass-and-sass-watch-reliable-compared-to-sass-tasks-on-task-runners-s) (that no one answered) just to share my experience with SASS compiling:

> **Grunt**: using grunt-contrib-sass - Everything has worked smoothly; I chose this one over grunt-sass for no particular reason, but I've read that the latter uses libsass(c++) which is faster than the traditional ruby Sass.
>
> **Gulp**: using gulp:sass - I often encounter an error when watching
>   files, it doesn´t find some partials, but if you save again,
>   everything is fine (this is addressed in their common issues -this
>   solution hasn't worked for me though), also it doesn't generate sass
>   maps as a default you have to use gulp-sourcemaps on top.
>
> **Straight from Console**: no task runners - Works fine so far, generates
>   sourcemaps, and lets you know where there's an error, just like with
>   Grunt and Gulp.

So after working on different projects using SASS I'd say the reasons are:

- Tutorials popularized the use of task runners when using SASS in its early times
- In a project, you rarely use SASS just by itself, you most likely want to run other tasks, so it makes sense to add your SASS task to the flow, which saves time and makes sense.
- It's easier to run a simple command such as `gulp sass` or just `gulp` to run the default gulp task (that should include the sass task) than to remember a long command in which you have to put the paths over and over again.

After a while I realized that you can use NPM scripts in your `package.json` to run the SASS command line tools like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets --style compressed"
  },
```

And then run it from the command line: `npm run sass`

the above requires no configuration and you don't have to remember the whole command by heart.

To conclude, there is nothing wrong in using the CMD SASS without other compilers/task runners, just use whatever you feel most comfortable with.